# Improving Rust binary build times

Tags: build, rust, compilation, linker

I’m just starting a Rust project and already it takes ~7.6s to build what I’d consider a simple binary.

I’m using async/await a lot and commenting out some awaits, like the await on my hyper server, can improve build performance by about 4s. But I’m not sure if that’s because building async/await is slow or by removing that await the Rust compiler no longer needs to build my HTTP response handling code.

```
// Removing the equivalent of this line (from https://hyper.rs) in
// my codebase improves build times by ~4s.
if let Err(e) = server.await {
    eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
}
```

I’m not using Cargo which means I’m manually generating `rustc` commands. Here’s part of a command I’m using for one of these binaries:

```
rustc admin/dev/server/main.rs --edition=2018 --crate-name=dev_server --crate-type=bin --target=x86_64-apple-darwin --codegen=opt-level=0 --codegen=debuginfo=2 --cap-lints=allow --emit=link --color=always ...
```

I’ve also abstracted my code into smaller crates. I was hoping that would mean Rust could skip recompilation of smaller crates and third-party dependencies (like hyper), but my guess is that binary codegen is what’s taking all the time?

What are techniques I can use for profiling my Rust build and techniques I can use for improving it? Is there anyway I can reuse compilation for dependencies which haven’t changed when rebuilding the binary? In development could I use dynamic linking for my dependencies instead of static linking?

Comment: Cargo will skip dependencies that haven't changed when compiling. If your build system doesn't you should consider using cargo instead. Cargo also offers a `--benches` [option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html) to learn where time is spent.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `cargo build`: it implements an incremental build, so it doesn't build dependencies every time, and only once. The first build is long, and all subsequent builds are fast. You need to use `cargo init` before that.
2. Use `cargo check` to quickly check and fix compilation errors. `cargo check` runs faster than `cargo build` because it doesn't do the final compilation step.
3. Attribute macros (like `#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]`) consumes a pretty decent amount of time usually, so pay attention.
4. Seems like there is an only manual way to identify a bottleneck of your build **time** consumption: remove some dependencies and look how the build time differs.
5. There is no way to specify dynamic linking just for development.

Comment: My build system doesn’t rebuild crates that haven’t changed but it isn’t using `--incremental`. Is that what you mean? When debugging Cargo it doesn’t look like it uses `--incremental` either.

Comment: `cargo build` should just work... You could try to use `cargo check` which shows you errors but runs faster because it doesn't do a final compilation step.

Answer (score 1):

Rust 1.60 allows you to run `cargo build --timings` which helps you identify slow components in the build.
As the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/timings.html) states:

> - Look for slow dependencies.
>
>   - Check if they have features that you may wish to consider disabling.
>   - Consider trying to remove the dependency completely.
> - Look for a crate being built multiple times with different versions.
> - Try to remove the older versions from the dependency graph.
> - Split large crates into smaller pieces.
> - If there are a large number of crates bottlenecked on a single crate, focus your attention on improving that one crate to improve
>   parallelism.